# Class with defined static constant values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, static, constants

I want to create a class that will contains static values accessable from all project.

Pseudocode:

```
class Constants:
  constant String API_URL : "http://api.service.com"
  constant Integer SOME_VALUE : 7
```

How can I do this with `Objective-C` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do it using preprocessors:

```
#define API_URL @"http://api.service.com"
#define SOME_VALUE (7)
```

Accessing defines would be simple: `[object do:API_URL];`

Or you could use constants

```
NSString * const apiURL = @"http://api.service.com";
NSNumber * const someValue = @7;
```

Accessing consts would be like accessing variables, So the string would just be a simple call. The NSNumber is an object wrapper for primitives so you'd need to access it like: `someValue.intValue`

Comment: It's worth noting that as a matter of style (and to avoid errors creeping in) those #defines should really be, eg, `#define SOME_VALUE (7)`.  I'd also strongly discourage this practice for non-embedded applications, as it's not type-checked, and the memory overhead of static variables really isn't a big deal for iOS/OS X.

Comment: Good points. Just wanted to throw out some options for him. edited.

Comment: For anyone coming across this in the future. Constants are definitely the preferred method. Constants allow the compiler to make some optimizations for you while defines simply improve your experience by auto completely common code.

Answer (score 16):

Answer for your question is **extern** keyword . I will explain it to you using an example . Add objective c classes your project and name them Common , Now in Common.h

```
     @interface Common : NSObject

     extern NSString *SiteApiURL;

     @end
```

After you defined an instance of NSString Class using the extern keyword what you need to do is switch to Common.m class and initialize the value for NSString (SiteApiURL)

```
     #import "Common.h"

     @implementation Common

     NSString *SiteApiURL = @"http://api.service.com";

     @end
```

Import the Common.h class within the project-Prefix.pch file like this

```
    #import <Availability.h>

    #ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
    #warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 3.0 and later."
    #endif

    #ifdef __OBJC__
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        #import "Common.h"
    #endif
```

All done , now you can use the object "SiteApiURL" anywhere in the whole project and you need not to import any class anywhere i.e. You can use this variable anywhere in the project directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Singleton` with all necessary constants [Here is a sample](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

If you do not want to create the class than you can use static private variables and static getters.

```
@interface

+(NSString*) getValue;

@end


@implementation

static NSString *_value = @"....";

+(NSString*) getValue {
   return _value;
}

@end
```

Comment: I do not need to init class - I just want to access properties in a static way.